# A book containing a large subset of known exact solutions to the EFEs

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations

I am looking for a good book which contains the known exact solutions to the [EFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations)s. A "library" of sorts.

I am aware that it's not really possible to get all of them in a single book, but at least one where it has a large amount of them?

I know someone who has a book like this. The title is something along the lines of "known exact solutions to the Field equations", but I can't find anything of it online.

Answer (score 5):

I found the book that I mentioned above:

H. Stephani, D. Kramer, M. MacCallum, C. Hoenselaers, E. Herlt, “Exact Solutions of Einstein’s Field Equations: 2nd Edition”, (2003), Cambridge University Press.

Comment: The book referenced here is more than a book that lists exact solutions to Einstein's field equations. They are systematically presented according to symmetries and other aspects of classifications.

Answer (score 1):

[Exact Space-Times in Einstein's General Relativity](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511635397) by Griffiths and Podolsky is another useful reference covering a variety of spacetimes.

It's worth noting though (as they do in this book), that looking for all "known exact solutions" is pretty ambiguous, since you don't actually solve anything to get one. You can postulate any spacetime you want, then decide whether it is reasonable based on some criteria (energy conditions, for example). Only if you also specify the matter fields, in which case you can solve the joint matter-gravitational field equations and find the stress tensor directly, can you decide if Einstein's equation is really solved --- but this is rarely done.